# Conversion failed error with dynamic SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

the query below throws this error :

`Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'query below that stops at WHERE tsv.Transition_ID =' to data type int`

```
DECLARE @Language_ID INT
SELECT @Language_ID = dbo.BPE_F_Default_Language_GetOne()

DECLARE @Transition_ID int
SET @Transition_ID = -1

DECLARE @SQLSTR nvarchar(4000)
SELECT @SQLSTR = 'SELECT tsv.Transition_Set_Variable_ID
                        , tsv.Set_To_Variable_ID
                        , tsv.Transition_ID
                        , tl.Transition_Text
                        , tsv.Variable_ID_To_Change
                        , variable.Name
                        , tsv.Set_To_Variable_ID
                        , tsv.Set_To_Value_ID
                        , tsv.Changed_In_SP
                        , tsv.Set_To_Comment_Input
                        , tsv.Comment AS Assigned_Comment
                        , variable2.Name AS Set_To_Variable_Name
                        , value.Name AS Set_To_Value_Name
                        FROM BPE_T_VA_Variable AS variable 
                        INNER JOIN BPE_T_VA_Transition_Set_Variable AS tsv 
                            ON variable.Variable_ID = tsv.Variable_ID_To_Change
                        LEFT JOIN BPE_T_VA_Variable AS variable2 
                            ON tsv.Set_To_Variable_ID = variable2.Variable_ID
                        LEFT JOIN BPE_T_VA_Value AS value 
                            ON tsv.Set_To_Value_ID = value.Value_ID
                        INNER JOIN BPE_T_WF_Transition_Localisation AS tl
                            ON tsv.Transition_ID = tl.WF_Transition_ID
                        WHERE tsv.Transition_ID = ' + @Transition_ID + ' OR ' + @Transition_ID + ' = -1 
                        AND (' + @Column + ' LIKE ''%''' + @search_string + '''%'' )
                        AND tl.Language_ID = ' + @Language_ID + '
                        ORDER BY tsv.Transition_ID, variable.Name'
EXEC(@SQLSTR);
```

Anyone know what this could be?

Comment: if you print the value of @SQLSTR before the exec, can you post the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Transition_ID` is an `INT`, and you have to convert it to a `VARCHAR` before concatenating it with the rest of your string.

However, it would be a better idea to use [`sp_executeSql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933299%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), and parameterize the `@Transition_ID` and `@search_string` parameters in your query.  As it currently stands, it is likely vulnerable to a [**Sql Injection Attack**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Additionally, be very careful with what values you allow into `@Column`, preferably by using a white-list, because this can't be parameterized the way that you're using it, and it also opens you up to attack.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are concatenating an `INT` to a string you must convert it or it will throw the error.

Add the following:

```
cast(@Transition_ID as varchar(50))
```

To make your full script:

```
DECLARE @Language_ID INT
SELECT @Language_ID = dbo.BPE_F_Default_Language_GetOne()

DECLARE @Transition_ID int
SET @Transition_ID = -1

DECLARE @SQLSTR nvarchar(4000)
SELECT @SQLSTR = 'SELECT tsv.Transition_Set_Variable_ID
                        , tsv.Set_To_Variable_ID
                        , tsv.Transition_ID
                        , tl.Transition_Text
                        , tsv.Variable_ID_To_Change
                        , variable.Name
                        , tsv.Set_To_Variable_ID
                        , tsv.Set_To_Value_ID
                        , tsv.Changed_In_SP
                        , tsv.Set_To_Comment_Input
                        , tsv.Comment AS Assigned_Comment
                        , variable2.Name AS Set_To_Variable_Name
                        , value.Name AS Set_To_Value_Name
                        FROM BPE_T_VA_Variable AS variable 
                        INNER JOIN BPE_T_VA_Transition_Set_Variable AS tsv 
                            ON variable.Variable_ID = tsv.Variable_ID_To_Change
                        LEFT JOIN BPE_T_VA_Variable AS variable2 
                            ON tsv.Set_To_Variable_ID = variable2.Variable_ID
                        LEFT JOIN BPE_T_VA_Value AS value 
                            ON tsv.Set_To_Value_ID = value.Value_ID
                        INNER JOIN BPE_T_WF_Transition_Localisation AS tl
                            ON tsv.Transition_ID = tl.WF_Transition_ID
                        WHERE tsv.Transition_ID = ' + cast(@Transition_ID as varchar(50)) + ' OR ' + cast(@Transition_ID as varchar(50)) + ' = -1 
                        AND (' + @Column + ' LIKE ''%''' + @search_string + '''%'' )
                        AND tl.Language_ID = ' + @Language_ID + '
                        ORDER BY tsv.Transition_ID, variable.Name'
EXEC(@SQLSTR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast your Int variables to varchar:

```
SELECT @SQLSTR = 'SELECT tsv.Transition_Set_Variable_ID
                        , tsv.Set_To_Variable_ID
                        , tsv.Transition_ID
                        , tl.Transition_Text
                        , tsv.Variable_ID_To_Change
                        , variable.Name
                        , tsv.Set_To_Variable_ID
                        , tsv.Set_To_Value_ID
                        , tsv.Changed_In_SP
                        , tsv.Set_To_Comment_Input
                        , tsv.Comment AS Assigned_Comment
                        , variable2.Name AS Set_To_Variable_Name
                        , value.Name AS Set_To_Value_Name
                        FROM BPE_T_VA_Variable AS variable 
                        INNER JOIN BPE_T_VA_Transition_Set_Variable AS tsv 
                            ON variable.Variable_ID = tsv.Variable_ID_To_Change
                        LEFT JOIN BPE_T_VA_Variable AS variable2 
                            ON tsv.Set_To_Variable_ID = variable2.Variable_ID
                        LEFT JOIN BPE_T_VA_Value AS value 
                            ON tsv.Set_To_Value_ID = value.Value_ID
                        INNER JOIN BPE_T_WF_Transition_Localisation AS tl
                            ON tsv.Transition_ID = tl.WF_Transition_ID
                        WHERE tsv.Transition_ID = ' + cast(@Transition_ID as varchar) + ' OR ' + cast(@Transition_ID as varchar) + ' = -1 
                        AND (' + @Column + ' LIKE ''%''' + @search_string + '''%'' )
                        AND tl.Language_ID = ' + cast(@Language_ID as varchar) + '
                        ORDER BY tsv.Transition_ID, variable.Name'
```

Answer (score 0):

isn't this causing you problems?

```
WHERE tsv.Transition_ID = ' + @Transition_ID + ' OR ' + @Transition_ID + ' = -1
```

I would think it would have to be

```
WHERE tsv.Transition_ID = ' + @Transition_ID + ' OR tsv.Transition_ID =' + @Transition_ID + ' = -1
```

since you're setting the value to -1, I would expect the SQL, if you printed it, to look like:

```
WHERE tsv.Transition_ID = -1 OR -1 = -1
```

was that the intention?

Comment: I think This would be a logical error, and not a conversion error.  My guess is that the query is right in this regard, since the value of `-1` is likely used to include all values and not filter by `tsv.Transition_ID` if the parameter uses this special value.

Comment: yes, it would be a different error, which is why I expect it will cause problems, though maybe after he's resolved this one.  Even if @transition_id = -1 means 'select all without a limit on this field' he's still building a string literal to execute, it has to be valid SQL.