# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string SQL Server 2012 in dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select * 
from abc 
where  
    ((@abcStartDate_From IS NULL AND @abcStartDate_To IS NULL) OR   
    ((StartDate > @LicenseStartDate_From) AND (@abcStartDate_To is NULL)) OR
    (DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, StartDate)) BETWEEN @abcStartDate_From AND @abcStartDate_To))
```

Note: `startdate` and parameters are `datetime`.

I want to write dynamic query but got an error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

I have used below as script for the dynamic query:

```
--('''+(convert(datetime,@abcStartDate_From,110))+''' IS NULL and  '''+(convert(datetime,@abcStartDate_To,110))+''' IS NULL  )OR    
--  ((convert(datetime,StartDate,110) > '''+(convert(datetime,@abcStartDate_From,110))+''') and ( '''+(convert(datetime,@abcStartDate_To,110))+''' is NULL)) OR
--  (DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, convert(datetime,StartDate,120)))  BETWEEN '''+(convert(datetime,@abcStartDate_From,110))+''' and '''+(convert(datetime,@abcStartDate_To,110))+''')'
```

---

```
((''' + convert(varchar(10), @abcExpirationDate_From, 120) + ''' IS NULL and  ''' + convert(varchar(10), @abcExpirationDate_To, 120) + ''' IS NULL  )OR 
--  ((A.StartDate > ''' + convert(varchar(10), @abcExpirationDate_From, 120) + ''') and ( ''' + convert(varchar(10), @abcExpirationDate_To, 120) + ''' is NULL)) OR
--  (DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, A.ExpiryDate))  BETWEEN ''' + convert(varchar(10), @abcExpirationDate_From, 120) + ''' and ''' + convert(varchar(10), @abcExpirationDate_To, 120) + ''' ) )'
```

---

```
('''+(convert(nvarchar(10),@abcStartDate_From,111))+''' IS NULL and  '''+(convert(nvarchar(10),@abcStartDate_To,111))+''' IS NULL  )OR  
    ((convert(nvarchar(10),StartDate,111) > '''+(convert(datetime,@abcStartDate_From,110))+''') and ( '''+(convert(nvarchar(10),@abcStartDate_To,111))+''' is NULL)) OR
    (DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, convert(nvarchar(10),StartDate,111)))  BETWEEN '''+(convert(nvarchar(10),@abcStartDate_From,111))+''' and '''+(convert(nvarchar(10),@abcStartDate_To,111))+''')'
```

But it didn't work for me. Could anyone help me to come out from this issues?

Comment: You need to post the actual code that is causing the error.   The query you posted is not dynamic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conversion failed error with dynamic SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805969/conversion-failed-error-with-dynamic-sql-query)

Comment: Please space the code for formatting, just like John did, four spaces before code lines.

Answer (score 0):

The error 'conversion failed' was the result of your incorrect use of the convert function -- datetime is the wrong data type for your use case.  varchar(10) is correct for conversion style 110.  You had that problem both in generating the dynamic sql, and later when executing the generated sql.

Your continuing problems seem to relate to the number of ticks.  The string just doesn't parse out correctly.  Consdier this instead (The 'select' keyword here is meant to output the generated string so we can review it for correctness.  It is not part of the final solution):

```
declare @abcStartDate_From datetime = '1/1/2000'
declare @abcStartDate_To datetime = '12/1/2000'

select '('''+(convert(varchar(10),@abcStartDate_From,110))+''' IS NULL and  '''+(convert(varchar(10),@abcStartDate_To,110))+''' IS NULL) OR    
  ((convert(datetime,StartDate,110) > '''+(convert(varchar(10),@abcStartDate_From,110))+''') and ( '''+(convert(varchar(10),@abcStartDate_To,110))+''' is NULL)) OR
  (DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, convert(datetime,StartDate,120)))  BETWEEN '''+(convert(varchar(10),@abcStartDate_From,110))+''' and '''+(convert(varchar(10),@abcStartDate_To,110))+''')'
```

this produces the statement to be executed (which is not a complete sql query so I take it to be part of a where clause, I hope).

```
  ('01-01-2000' IS NULL and  '12-01-2000' IS NULL) OR    
  ((convert(datetime,StartDate,110) > '01-01-2000') and ( '12-01-2000' is NULL)) OR
  (DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, convert(datetime,StartDate,120)))  BETWEEN '01-01-2000' and '12-01-2000')
```

Next, your logic has lots of problems.  If @abcStartDate_From is null, then the convert function will produce a null.  Concatenating nulls with the '+' operator will cause the resulting string to be null regardless of other strings in the concatenation.  Your dynamic sql seems to 'handle' cases when the variable is null, but the string itself will never be produced if the variable is null.  See the problem? You need to test your variables for nulls before generating the dynamic sql, and then produce different sql based on the different cases those values represent.

Next:

Why are you doing this dateadd logic?  This statement:

```
DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, convert(varchar(10),StartDate,120)))
```

is equal to StartDate.  I don't see a reason for doing it.

Anyway, hope it helps.  Good luck.